# Determining stability of equilibrium points for a non linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

Given the system:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{}
\dot x=-x^3y^2 \\ 
\dot y = -2x^2y^3
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I need to find the equilibrium points and to determine whether the system is stable around them. I'v found $(0,0)$ to be a stable equilibrium point, using the Lyapunov function $V(x)=x^2+y^2$.

The rest of the equilibrium points are $(x_0,0), (0,y_0) \; , \; x_0,y_0 \in \Bbb R$. I'm having trouble with determining wether they are stable or not. Linearization is not useful in this case, and I couldn't find any Lyapunov function.

Comment: Just asking... why linearization is not useful?

Comment: The equilibiruim points are not hyperbolic, meaning we can't use the linearization theorem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a hint:

Your system is
$$
\frac{d}{dt}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{pmatrix}
=
x^2 y^2
\begin{pmatrix}
-x \\ -2y
\end{pmatrix}
,
$$
which only differs from the linear system
$$
\frac{d}{dt}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-x \\ -2y
\end{pmatrix}
$$
by the nonnegative factor $x^2 y^2$.

This means that except for the $x$ and $y$ axes (where $x^2 y^2=0$), the trajectories for your system will be the same as for the linear system, up to a reparametrization of time.

Using this, you should be able to see what happens if you perturb an equilibrium $(x_0,0)$ or $(0,y_0)$ a little (so that you move off the axis).

Comment: Do you mean that for each starting point, the solution will convert to the point $(0,0)$, meaning the system is unstable for every other equilibrium point?

Comment: Exactly! (For any starting point *off the axes*, to be precise, but I suppose that's what you meant.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Very nice thinking, but is this claim formal enough? I'm not sure I completely understand why the trajectories of my system will be the same as the linear system up to reparametrization of time.

Comment: Yes, it's rigorous. Given a trajectory $(x(s),y(s))$ of one system, one can let $s=s(t)$ and derive an ODE that $s$ has to satisfy in order for $(x(s(t)),y(s(t)))$ to be a solution of the other system. The solution of that ODE gives the reparametrization. (Intuitively, it's quite clear that the *phase portrait* only depends on the *direction* of the vector field; the *magnitude* is only important if you want to know how *fast* you are moving along the trajectory at any given point – exactly the information which is suppressed in the phase portrait.)